# Child activity extending parent that extends listActivity

Tags: android, extend, listactivity

I have a main screen that contains a listview, so I extended ListActivity for that class and linked the listview to a DB - all fine.

But I then call a new (child?) activity which extends the first activity and this new activity does NOT have a listView. However, I get a run-time error telling me I need a listView:

```
02-26 05:43:20.749: E/AndroidRuntime(1080): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

I'm in the process of just changing my parent class to just extend Activity but it's annoying - is this the only way forward or is there a better way?

EDIT: not sure if it helps, these are my class declarations:

```
public class FirstScreenActivity extends ListActivity {
....

public class createNewVehicleActivity extends FirstScreenActivity {
....
```

Comment: if you using list activity you must need to give your list id as 'android.R.id.list' in your layout xml

Comment: Yes, I know - and I do have a listview in the first activity but I don't need one in the second activity, which extends the first. Is there no way of telling the VM to not worry about the fact the second activity does not have a listview?

Comment: instead of using listactivity use activity,but i can't understand your question,the error causes due to the above reason only

Comment: can you post your second activity code?

Answer (score 0):

both the layout of the  parent and child `Activity` must have a ListView with id

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Comment: Yes, I know - and I do have a listview in the first activity but I don't need one in the second activity, which extends the first. Is there no way of telling the VM to not worry about the fact the second activity does not have a listview?